# How To Change The Size Of The Window For A SpriteKit Project

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I'm just messing around with a Objective C (OS X) SpriteKit project. I'm trying to make the window (frame) be the same size as my scene. I've changed my scene to be (1366, 768), but my frame was still (800, 600). To fix this I added the following code to `ViewController.m`:

```
[self.skView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1366, 768)];
```

That did the trick, but now when I display things in my scene (0, 0) is in the middle of the screen as opposed to the bottom left corner. How do you fix this? Or is there another way to change the size of the frame so that the origin position is NOT changed from the bottom left corner?

Comment: I apologize...this was a stupid question. I always thought that the anchor point of a SKScene was (0, 0), but it appear to be (0.5, 0.5). I'm not sure if it was always like that or if it has changed over the last year or two. Either way, adding `[scene setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];` after the scene is created in `ViewController.m` fixed it all.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer so if someone stumbles across this in the future, they have an answer to refer to.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize...this was a stupid question, but hopefully this answer will help someone out.

I always thought that the anchor point of a SKScene was (0, 0), but it appear to be (0.5, 0.5). I'm not sure if it was always like that or if it has changed over the last year or two. Either way, adding `[scene setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];` after the scene is created in the `ViewController` class fixed it all making the bottom left of the screen (0, 0). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It is not that scene's anchor point is changed. When you create a scene in other way than loading it from .sks file you will notice that its [anchorPoint is stil 0.0, 0.0](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519864-anchorpoint). It is just a default value of .sks file what is changed since Xcode 8.

Comment: Yes, but the default way of loading a scene when you create a SpriteKit project is via an .sks file. I just didn't realize that the default value for the anchor point had changed.

Comment: Of course. But the point is that anchorPoint isn't really changed. Docs says the same.

Comment: Are we saying the same thing? I wasn't going to post an answer because I realized my question was dumb, but another poster told me to post it just in case someone else runs into the same bit of confusion.

Comment: No you are correct about the fact that anchorPoint is altered to 0.5, 0.5 in sks files. But generally, a default value of scene's anchorPoint is still 0.0,0.0. Just read the link I've posted.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, that's completely correct. So basically we're talking about two different ways of creating and the default anchor points that are used in each case. Cool.